# Can create a def in python class which can be called what ever the def name even if the def didn't exist

Tags: python, function

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
class MyClass(Object):
    def ****(self):
        print self.__name __

MyClass.test()
->test

MyClass.whatever()
->whatever
```

So you can call any method and it prints the name.

Comment: why do you need to print inside the function, why can't you just do `print ****.__name__`? put it in a try-except and catch the NameError.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a [`__getattr__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) on your class to intercept access attempts on unknown attributes, and return a function (which you could bind to the class):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def echo():
            return name
        return echo
```

This returns unbound functions, with no reference to the instance.

You do need to create an instance first for this to work:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         def echo():
...             return name
...         return echo
... 
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.test()
'test'
>>> instance.whatever()
'whatever'
```

You can bind the function to the instance (so it gets `self` passed in) by manually invoking the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), calling `__get__` on the function before returning:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def echo(self):
            return '{}.{}'.format(type(self).__name__, name)
        return echo.__get__(self, type(self))
```

With access to `self` we can print a little more information:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         def echo(self):
...             return '{}.{}'.format(type(self).__name__, name)
...         return echo.__get__(self, type(self))
... 
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.test()
'MyClass.test'
>>> instance.whatever()
'MyClass.whatever'
```